# keras - Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification

I've been trying to create a 7 columns (features) model with Keras functional API and map it to the a 6 classes output.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate

input_message = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_message)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_message = Model(inputs=input_message, outputs=x)

input_description = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_description)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_description = Model(inputs=input_description, outputs=x)

input_errors = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_errors)
model_errors = Model(inputs=input_errors, outputs=x)

input_panics = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_panics)
model_panics = Model(inputs=input_panics, outputs=x)

input_images = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_images)
model_images = Model(inputs=input_images, outputs=x)

input_committer = Input(shape=(16,))
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(input_description)
model_committer = Model(inputs=input_committer, outputs=x)

input_reporter = Input(shape=(6,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_reporter)
model_reporter = Model(inputs=input_reporter, outputs=x)

combined = Concatenate()([model_message.output, model_description.output, model_errors.output, 
                         model_panics.output, model_images.output, model_committer.output, model_reporter.output])

z = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[model_message.input, model_description.input, model_errors.input, 
                     model_panics.input, model_images.input, model_committer.input, model_reporter.input], 
              outputs=z)
```

Sadly it was resulted in the below error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_23'), name='input_23', description="created by layer 'input_23'") at layer "dense_74". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

My feature list is as follows:

1. message - text
2. description - text
3. has_errors - int represents a bool value
4. has_panics - int represents a bool value
5. has_images - int represents a bool value
6. committer groups - categorical inputs
7. reporter group - categorical inputs - 6 possible values overall

I've been trying to follow the below link:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

so 2 questions:

1. what yields the above error?
2. Shouldn't I apply some kind of embedding for the text?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the variable names that you have. Usually the `GraphDisconnected` error is caused by having overriding names in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating so many models when you actually want one?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate

input_message = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_message)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x1 = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)

input_description = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_description)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x2 = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)

input_errors = Input(shape=(2,))
x3 = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_errors)

input_panics = Input(shape=(2,))
x4 = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_panics)

input_images = Input(shape=(2,))
x5 = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_images)

input_committer = Input(shape=(16,))
x6 = Dense(4, activation="relu")(input_description)

input_reporter = Input(shape=(6,))
x7 = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_reporter)

combined = Concatenate()([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7])

z = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[input_message,input_description,input_errors,input_panics,input_images,input_committer,input_reporter ], 
              outputs=z)
```

I haven't run it but this seems like it could work to me.

Comment: So many models? there's only 1.
Since I've 7 features/columns I'm creating an input for each

Answer (score 1):

It is a relatively old post, and most likely @Ben has already resolved this issue. For those who may have a similar problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate

input_message = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_message)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_message = Model(inputs=input_message, outputs=x)

input_description = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_description)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_description = Model(inputs=input_description, outputs=x)

input_errors = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_errors)
model_errors = Model(inputs=input_errors, outputs=x)

input_panics = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_panics)
model_panics = Model(inputs=input_panics, outputs=x)

input_images = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_images)
model_images = Model(inputs=input_images, outputs=x)

input_committer = Input(shape=(16,))
#x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(input_description) #<======== passing a wrong tensor of the shape of (128,)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(input_committer) #<======== passing the correct tensor with the shape of (16,)
model_committer = Model(inputs=input_committer, outputs=x)

input_reporter = Input(shape=(6,))
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(input_reporter)
model_reporter = Model(inputs=input_reporter, outputs=x)

combined = Concatenate()([model_message.output, model_description.output, model_errors.output, 
                         model_panics.output, model_images.output, model_committer.output, model_reporter.output])

z = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[model_message.input, model_description.input, model_errors.input, 
                     model_panics.input, model_images.input, model_committer.input, model_reporter.input], 
              outputs=z)
```

Here is the graph of the model:

[image]

---

**Notes on debugging**

- TensorFlow-Keras generally generates insightful errors/warnings that can help significantly when debugging such issues.
- When running the original code on my system, the beginning part of the error  I get is:

> ```
>      29 input_committer = Input(shape=(16,))
>      30 x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(input_description)
> ---> 31 model_committer = Model(inputs=input_committer, outputs=x)
>      32 
>      33 input_reporter = Input(shape=(6,))
> ```

This suggests there are some issues with `model_committer = Model(inputs=input_committer, outputs=x)`.

- At the end of the generated error, I get:

> ```
> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.float32,
> name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer
> 'input_2'") at layer "dense_9". The following previous layers were
> accessed without issue: []
> ```

It suggests that a `KerasTensor` of the shape of `(None, 128)` and the name of `input_2` cannot be processed properly ***at layer "dense_9"***.

We can see what is going wrong here:

the model `model_committer` is called on the `KerasTensor` of `input_description` of the shape of (128,) instead of `input_committer` of the shape of (16,).

- The tensor of `input_description` (if one runs a fresh session) is named `input_2` since it is created by layer `input_2 (the second input tensor created).
- The problematic tensor cannot be processed properly ***at layer "dense_9"*** which is the 10th dense layer created in a fresh session (dense layers are named `dense`, `dense_1`, `dense_2`, etc.).

**Finally, I recommended the layers to be named explicitly upon their creation (by passing the `name` argument). It enables an easier debugging as well as more convenient analysis of each layer after training.**